# What does this scoring format mean?

Tags: football, scoring

Looking at this soccer match page: http://www.espnfc.com/en/report/233737/report.html?soccernet=true&cc=null

The score format says, "(2) 3 - 2 (3)". What do the brackets mean? The article also says:

> After 90 minutes Sevilla led 3-2 to cancel out the first-leg deficit
>   and make the score 5-5 on aggregate and with no goals in extra-time,
>   it was left to visiting goalkeeper Volkan, who saved from Julien
>   Escude, Ivica Dragutinovic and Dani Alves.

What do they mean by "first-leg deficit" and "score 5-5 on aggregate"?

Comment: Forgot to mention "first-leg deficit" in my answer below. In the first leg, Sevilla had lost 3-2, giving them a 1 goal deficit. However, one must also consider the away goal rule, but I'll refer to my answer below for more information on that!

Answer (score 1):

The Champions League uses a [two-legged tie format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-legged_tie): the teams play a match at each home stadium and the overall winner advances. This (nearly) eliminates the [home-field effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_advantage).

In this match, Fenerbahçe had [won its home leg by a score of 3-2](http://www.fenerbahce.org/eng/detay.asp?ContentID=1694), so Sevilla needed to win 3-2 to tie the aggregate score at 5-5 and send the match to a shootout.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to consider here:

**1. The two-legged tie format**

> Knockout phase
>   From the last 16 until the semi-finals, clubs play two matches against each other on a home-and-away basis with the same rules as the qualifying and play-off rounds applied. In the last 16, group winners play runners-up other than teams from their own pool or nation, while from the quarter-finals on the draw is free.    (source: uefa.com)

This means that the two teams face eachother twice; once at home, and once away. There are several reasons use this format, among them the fact that it's more fair and that it's economically beneficial.

**2. The away goal rule**

Even though it didn't come into play in this particular example, the "away goal rule" is still very important, especially when considering the term "aggregate score". The *aggregate score* is the "total score" over the two games - and also the main way of determining the winner of the two-legged tie. In this case, the aggregate score was 5-5, as both teams had won with 3-2 at their respective home stadium.

When the aggregate score is a tie, one team can still be declared the winner - due to the *away goal rule*. Let us say that the 2nd game (in Sevilla) had ended 2-1 (instead of 3-2). The aggregate score would then have been 4-4, but Sevilla would have been declared the winner. This is because Sevilla scored 2 goals away, while Fenerbahce only scored one. Thus, the only way a game in the Champions League can go to extra time and penalties, is if both legs end the same way - as the game between Sevilla and Fenerbahce did.

For further reading, take a look at the [Champions League regulations](http://www.uefa.com/MultimediaFiles/Download/Regulations/competitions/Regulations/01/94/62/34/1946234_DOWNLOAD.pdf), and in particular articles 7-8.